# How to translate "It serves you right"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

“It serves you right” is used when what you get is a result of your actions.
How can I say it in French?

Answer (score 22):

I think there are several ways to translate this, with different levels of language:

- *Bien fait pour toi !* (probably the most commonly used)
- *Ça t'apprendra !* (also quite common)
- *Ça te fera les pieds !* (seems a bit outdated)
- *Bien fait pour ta gueule !* (vulgar, but still used)

Comment: Instead of "*Ça te fera les pieds !*", and not necessarily outdated: "*Ça te fera les pattes !*" (un peu familier, cependant).

Comment: @Bruno I have never heard this expression before, but it seems after searching indeed that it is used. Thanks for adding this ! I'm curious, how familiar is this compared to the 4th element in my list?

Comment: I'd say it's familiar but not vulgar, at least it doesn't have the same offensive connotations as "*Bien fait pour ta gueule !*".

Answer (score 8):

*Tu l'as bien mérité* est aussi [très à la mode](http://www.viedemerde.fr/) en ce moment.

*Tu l'as bien mérité* is also very simple. It translates to "you deserved it" and is used as such on the french version of the popular [FML website](http://www.fmylife.com/).

Answer (score 8):

Autre proposition :

> Tu ne l'as pas volé (celui là).

ou

> Tu l'as bien cherché.

Par exemple : un enfant taquine son frère sans relâche. Ce dernier finit par lui donner un coup de poing dans les côtes. Le parent à l'enfant qui pleure : « Arrêtes de pleurnicher, tu l'avais bien cherché ! ».

Answer (score 7):

Je traduirais par :

> Ça t'apprendra.

Answer (score 4):

J'ai trouvé qu'on peut aussi dire :

> C'est bien fait pour vous/toi !

Answer (score 4):

You could translate this expression by :

> Cela te servira de leçon.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the proverb:

> On récolte ce que l'on sème.

whose english version is:

> One reaps what one sows.

which is indeed used to express the fact that one always get the results of its actions.

Comment: You could also mention "Qui sème le vent, récolte la tempête", which doesn't convey the exact same meaning though, implying consequences are worse than your bad actions.

Comment: Je ne crois pas avoir déjà entendu ce proverbe "On récolte ce que l'on a semé", et quand je cherche cette phrase sur internet je ne trouve que des sites de traduction qui la proposent comme traduction du proverbe anglais. Est-ce que ce proverbe est réellement utilisé en français... ? Et la tournure "on récolte ce que l'on sème" m'aurait parue plus naturelle.

Comment: J'ai édité mon commentaire, la tournure "on récolte ce que l'on sème" semble en effet un peu plus naturelle. Le fait est que cette expression est souvent utilisée au passé pour dire "Tu récoltes simplement ce que tu as semé.".
J'utilise ce proverbe et je l'ai déjà lu dans certains ouvrages. Celui-ci a dû passer dans la culture française depuis un certain temps. Premier exemple trouvé dans le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9colter_ce_que_l%E2%80%99on_a_sem%C3%A9).